# Why do all code errors in questions need to be reproducible?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

Why do all code errors in questions need to be reproducible? Some are very simple and don't need to be reproduced.

> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Not every code problem needs to be reproduced to know the answer. Some questions rely on the knowledge of the answerer.

"Why is the `let` statement in Apple's Swift Programming Language immutable?" That doesn't need to be reproduced, since a basic knowledge of Swift is all you need to answer the question.

That leads to one of my questions, which was recently closed: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956444/why-do-you-have-to-use-elmsindex-to-access-an-element"

My question was closed because it isn't reproducible. Not every code error needs to be reproducible, again! That code problem relies on the answerer's knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/234152/1947286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this close reason is a bit suspect - it's not really related to a reproducible code problem per se.

In all honesty though, the answer is, "It doesn't, you're synthesizing a false property."  This is covered by the original answer, so I'm bewildered as to why you created a new question to discuss it.

The close reason is incorrect, no two ways about it.  I personally wouldn't *close* this question, but I wouldn't favor it highly either. It'd take a few minutes of research on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to prove whether or not this property existed.

Comment: "or a simple typographical error". `elms` ne `elems`. Seems clear, it's the close reason I'd go for.